# How to bind a Kendo UI list to a ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, kendo-ui

I have this fallowing list:

```
<ul data-template="view" data-bind="source: contacts"></ul>

...
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="view">
    <li>
        <div data-role="button" data-bind="click: viewContact">
            <h4>#: first_name #</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

var someClass = kendo.observable({
    title    : 'Contact',
    contacts : [],

    getContacts: function () {
        var data = new Contacts().get();

        $.when(data()).then(function (data) {
            someClass.contacts = data;
        });
    }
});
```

I want to assign `data` from `getContacts` to `products` and populate the template with results as they come in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you are talking about "products" but in the code snippet i see "contacts".

In any case, you need to do the following:

```
someClass.set('contacts', data)
```

Note: assuming you have contacts as a property on the viewmodel.

Since its an observable object, if you don't use get() & set() methods, kendo wont know who all are observing that property. If you use set() method to set new value, Kendo will propagate the change and will notify the listeners of the property.

Comment: ill give this a try, sorry for the var names confusion. thanks